# Sorting objects in array when 2 property have same value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have array like below. I wanted to sort these based on object parameter `a_weight`. I am not able to do this and second thing is this key `a_weight` can have same value in different objects like show below. Any help sorting this?

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a_priority] => 1
            [a_roleobjectid] => 1
            [a_roleid] => 1
            [a_objectid] => 1
            [a_objecttypeid] => 2
            [a_name] => Object Type
            [a_path] => abc/b
            [a_createddate] => 2012-10-08 11:00:00
            [a_createdby] => 1
            [a_modifieddate] => 2012-10-08 11:05:50
            [a_modifiedby] => 1
            [a_weight] => 1
            [a_cancreate] => 1
            [a_canread] => 1
            [a_canupdate] => 1
            [a_candelete] => 1
            [a_canprint] => 1
            [a_canexport] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a_priority] => 1
            [a_roleobjectid] => 2
            [a_roleid] => 1
            [a_objectid] => 2
            [a_objecttypeid] => 2
            [a_name] => Object
            [a_path] => abc/a
            [a_createddate] => 2012-10-08 11:00:00
            [a_createdby] => 1
            [a_modifieddate] => 2012-10-08 11:05:50
            [a_modifiedby] => 1
            [a_weight] => 3
            [a_cancreate] => 1
            [a_canread] => 1
            [a_canupdate] => 1
            [a_candelete] => 1
            [a_canprint] => 1
            [a_canexport] => 1
        )
[2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a_priority] => 1
            [a_roleobjectid] => 3
            [a_roleid] => 1
            [a_objectid] => 3
            [a_objecttypeid] => 2
            [a_name] => Role
            [a_path] => abc/r
            [a_createddate] => 2012-10-08 11:00:00
            [a_createdby] => 1
            [a_modifieddate] => 2012-10-08 15:19:02
            [a_modifiedby] => 1
            [a_weight] => 1
            [a_cancreate] => 1
            [a_canread] => 1
            [a_canupdate] => 1
            [a_candelete] => 1
            [a_canprint] => 1
            [a_canexport] => 1
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the `uasort` function. More info at http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

an example for your case would be:

```
function mysort($a, $b){
    return $a->a_weight < $b->a_weight ? -1 : 1;
}
$objects = uasort($objects, 'mysort');
```